# How to tell if a state was reached by back button in AngularJS (using uirouter)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS app (using uirouter), and would like to be able to tell whether the current state was reached by the user clicking the back button.

I can't find that anywhere in $state or $stateParams, and the javascript API's are very restrictive when it comes to accessing history items.

Alternatively, if I could tell that the current state had a 'reload: true' forced on it, that would work as well.